# wp_generate_attachment_metadata for non-images files

Tags: uploads, attachments, array

I created a frontend form for upload images and worked fine.

The only problem is that I need generate attachment metadata for non images file. Now, metadata is only created for images files.

I'm using these lines for generate and insert metadata:

```
$attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
```

**SOLVED**

I made a verification to check if `$attachment_data` is empty (non-images files, like PDF):

```
if(empty($attachment_data)){
    $fileMeta = array('file' => $imageUrl);
    add_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', $fileMeta);
}else{
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_generate_metatadata()` should create metadata for image, video, and audio file types. There is and `if`/`elseif` conditional [in the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L72) that limits the function to those three. However, the last line is:

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', $metadata, $attachment_id );
```

So you could use the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` filter to generate the metadata you want. There are plenty of answers here about creating filters, not to mention [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

It is hard to say much more as you don't specify so much as what kind of "non-image" file you have.